# IPv6 quits working after using VPN

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, vpn, ipv6

My Macbook Pro running Mavericks picks up my ISP's (native) IPv6 support with automatic configuration just fine on bootup. I'm using an AirPort Extreme 802.11ac (2013) with default settings.

If then connect to an IPv4-only VPN, I lose IPv6 connectivity, as expected.

However, when I disconnect from the VPN, my Macbook Pro will not pick up IPv6 from my ISP until I reboot, as *not* expected. Configuration remains on Automatic, it just won't configure itself.

How can I make it immediately reconnect to IPv6 when I quit the VPN?

Comment: Are you using an AirPort Extreme, or some other router (and if so, which one)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The 2013 Extreme.

Comment: If you turn wifi off and back on (reconnect to AP Extreme), does that also fix IPv6? Perhaps you could post the output of `netstat` in Terminal.app both before starting the VPN and after disconnecting?

Comment: Wait, which version of Mac OS X are you running?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Mavericks.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this?  I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Currently experiencing a slightly different issue on 10.10.5 clients. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer yet. Can you post the routing tables in both states? On the Terminal: `netstat -arn`